# Measure Remaining Time Left to use Function

Tags: c++

I want to make a function that references the last time the function was called to ensure that it can only be called at most every 10 seconds:

```cpp
void SetUseFunctionLastTime()
    {
        std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

        bool UseFunction()
        {
            if (/*Code here*/) /*HERE: I want to check the remaining time 
                               left before I can call it again*/
            {
                Log("Wait %d seconds to use this", seconds_left)
                return false;
            }

        SetUseFunctionLastTime()
    }
```

How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <chrono>

bool UseFunction() {
    constexpr std::chrono::duration<double> interval_seconds{ 10.0 };
    static std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> last_call{ std::chrono::steady_clock::now() };
    const auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    const auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now - last_call);
    const auto seconds_left = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(interval_seconds - elapsed_time).count();
    if (seconds_left > 0) {
        printf("Wait %lld seconds to use this\n", seconds_left);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        last_call = now;
        printf("Returning true.\n");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-` operator to take the time difference:

```
void SetUseFunctionLastTime()
{
    last_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}

bool UseFunction()
{
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - last_time;
    auto seconds_left = diff.count();
    if (seconds_left < 10) 
    {
        Log("Wait %d seconds to use this", seconds_left);
        return false;
    }
    SetUseFunctionLastTime();
}
```

Comment: It's says that count is undeclared

Comment: Perhaps you're typing `count` instead of `count()`?